# Overload dereferencing operator (operator*())

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, dereference

Here is my operator definition in my class :

```
T& operator*(){
        return this->element_; 
}
```

When I use it like that, it is called :

```
std::cout << n->operator*() << std::endl;
```

It doesn't, if I try :

```
std::cout << *n << std::endl;
```

Any Idea ?

Thanks in advance,

Jérémy

Comment: What is the type of `n`, and where is the operator defined?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like `n` is itself a pointer, so you need `**n`